# slideToggle issue with stop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).find("p").slideToggle("normal");
        return false;
    });
});
```

With this piece of jQuery code I can make elements slide in and out. But the problem is that when someone clicks real fast, the slide out will only go until the max height is reached of the latest reached height.

So, if someone would click real fast the element will only slide out a couple of pixels and slide back up. If they´d than click again to slide it out, it will only slide out to the max height it reached the last time.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue to make this work proper?

*PS: The height of the p element is set to auto so it automaticly matches the height of the content inside (maybe this detail will help with your answer).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").click(function() {
        if ( ! $(this).find('p:animated').length)
        {
            $(this).find("p").slideToggle("normal");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `click` function to attach the click event, use `one` instead:

```
$("ul li").one("click", doStuff);

function doStuff(){ 
   // do your stuff here
   $("ul li").one("click", doStuff); // Re-attach event
}
```

and then re-attach the event in the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually process the additional clicks (rather than ignore them), then  you want to use `.stop(true, true)` to stop the previous animation and jump it to the conclusion so your next animation can run as you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).find("p").stop(true, true).slideToggle("normal");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Whenever you trigger an animation from a user click, you should know about `.stop()` and figure out which arguments you want to use with it for a given situation.  Without it, the animations can pile up in the queue and run sequentially which is usually not what you want.

Here's the [jQuery reference info](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on `.stop()` and it's arguments.